# Для чего wrapper в начале верстки со значением min-height:100% overflow: hidden?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Учусь верстке по роликам на ютубе, многие в начале верстки создают обертку с такими стилями и не раскрывают суть для чего и какая польза от этой записи

```
.wrapper {
   min-height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

overflow: hidden еще можно понять, чтобы элементы прятались за границами, а вот min-height зачем, если его указывают в % а процент наследуется от родителя, а верстка то пустая? Объясните этот момент пожалуйста, для чего такое могут применять?

Comment: При пустой вёрстке родитель — окно браузера, от которого скорее всего и унаследуется высота

Answer (score 1):

Для того, что-бы при отсутствии контента блок .wrapper не схлопывался а был всегда сто процентов по высоте. Див по умолчанию имеет ширину сто процентов, а высоту автоматическую. Потому при отсутствии контента высота схлопывается до нуля.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: black;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -150px;
  color: white;
}

.footer>h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="footer">
  <h1>Footer</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: А как это может быть полезно? Для чего это пишут? Вы это сами используете? @Andrei

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что польза тут чисто из-за overflow: hidden? Ну и например цвет фона всей страницы можно задать, т.к body не принято такое приписывать

Comment: @28Lucky Польза в том, что когда по дизайну у вас блок должен быть, а его не будет видно если в нем не будет контента или блок будет по размеру контента получается меньше чем задумано по дизайну и выглядит не красиво. Страница на которой контента мало и футер например будет по среди экрана. Это как-то странно и не красиво будет выглядеть.

Comment: @28Lucky Я немного изменил код. Для понимания попробуйте у враппера убрать минимальную высоту.

Comment: @28Lucky И правильно говорить, что проценты рассчитываются  согласно свободному пространству у родителя, а не то что они наследуются от родителя.

Comment: спасибо вам за подробное объяснение. Подытожив, чтобы футер снизу был и блок с контентом был виден. Спасибо вам. Нашел еще что вот так делают html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.main{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.footer {
  background-color: black;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.footer>h1 {
  margin: 0;
}</code>

Comment: а вот например на 2к, 4к мониторах пустоe пространство появляется если +- контент есть и это полноценная страница, https://prnt.sc/-6eFhkDDcsJ5           Как с этим можно бороться, кроме как еще контента добавить?

Comment: попробуйте масштаб уменьшить у странички в браузере https://codepen.io/nvdfxx/pen/JjdKQRY